grub rescue while booting from an external device
I have been to many places but with no success. Finally I have used Ubuntu live USB to boot and have obtained the Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary report (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZdMSHrvscz/).
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp fat part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 starts 
                       at sector -1082400768. But according to the info from 
                       fdisk, sdb2 starts at sector 3212566528.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdc and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sdb4
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 8 or 10 on sda4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 68IRR Ver. F.40(15.64) from Hewlett-Packard
The firmware is EFI-compatible, but this live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


1bd41042ef7c95517859160e13267d17   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
1bd41042ef7c95517859160e13267d17   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
9098faa654aeba2787562be78aa1cd08   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb4    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sdb4    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb4    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: BD1C7F3A-229C-4A9A-8F0C-0415D8638527
         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
sda2     206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3     239616  419430399 419190784 199.9G Microsoft basic data
sda4  419430400  999189207 579758808 276.5G Microsoft basic data
sda5  999190528 1000212479   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdc: 14.32 GiB, 15376000000 bytes, 30031250 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdc1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sdc2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sdc3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdc4  12115968 30029823 17913856  8.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x38d02e4d
     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1             2048 3212566527 3212564480   1.5T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2       3212566528 3213670399    1103872   539M 83 Linux
sdb3       3213670400 3229296639   15626240   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sdb4       3229296640 3907028991  677732352 323.2G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:512GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA 512GB EVM SSD:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
3:123MB:215GB:215GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:215GB:512GB:297GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:512GB:512GB:523MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;
sdb:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:Seagate Expansion:;
1:1049kB:1645GB:1645GB:ntfs::;
2:1645GB:1645GB:565MB:fat32::;
3:1645GB:1653GB:8001MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:1653GB:2000GB:347GB:ext4::;
sdc:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:SanDisk Ultra:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:15.4GB:9172MB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     A46E-AAD4                            19942941-a2d4-4174-b486-8d13cec12823                          EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               c0d5100e-d9b0-45e8-a85f-65fb6bede3be                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     4A88DA9C88DA85BB                     d8a3ded0-8313-4b2d-a89f-8234d15f8b1e                          Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     A4DC75EFDC75BC5C                     b6f9082c-6434-4eaf-a5c7-1be20f8a5ae5                          Basic data partition
└─sda5 ntfs     CAC001DAC001CD9F                     b6f4bfcb-52be-4d1b-bf30-1984fcdd88f2                          
sdb                                                                                                                
├─sdb1 ntfs     72F41DF9F41DC071                     38d02e4d-01                          Seagate Expansion Drive  
├─sdb2 vfat     E6E8-5C38                            38d02e4d-02                                                   
├─sdb3 swap     789b504e-95e2-4b78-a8e9-53469dc44f85 38d02e4d-03                                                   
└─sdb4 ext4     5ab77b2b-5e26-40cf-9167-2c502ef82797 38d02e4d-04                                                   
sdc    iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdc1 iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdc2 vfat     3C53-CAEB                            eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdc3                                               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sdc4 ext4     ce5f364d-7b95-4074-a6a1-d42bdaaf3512 c3c19732-f5ba-470b-9350-32b70b2b6d83 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                      69.5M  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3                                                     199.8G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4                                                       253G   8% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5                                                      88.4M  82% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sdb1                                                       1.1T  25% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb2                                                     531.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdb4                                                     295.1G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdc1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb2                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb4                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdc1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

==================== sdb2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1

====================== sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   5ab77b2b-5e26-40cf-9167-2c502ef82797
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb4/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/789b504e-95e2-4b78-a8e9-53469dc44f85 none swap sw 0 0
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5ab77b2b-5e26-40cf-9167-2c502ef82797 / ext4 defaults 0 1

======================= sdb4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sdb4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
1822.383476257 = 1956.769357824 boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
1822.385536194 = 1956.771569664 boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
1543.276615143 = 1657.080647680 boot/vmlinuz                                   1
1543.276615143 = 1657.080647680 boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
1543.276615143 = 1657.080647680 boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
1566.144195557 = 1681.634525184 boot/initrd.img                                3
1566.144195557 = 1681.634525184 boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               3
1566.144195557 = 1681.634525184 boot/initrd.img.old                            3

===================== sdb4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb4,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. 

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
``


You have mixed UEFI boot of Windows and BIOS boot of Ubuntu. Since seperate drives, technically that can work with hassles. Some systems know which way install is, others require you to go into UEFI/BIOS settings and change boot mode. You also have sdb as very old MBR(msdos) partitioned. But conversion to gpt, highly suggested for UEFI boot, will totally erase drive including your NTFS data. Or full backup required. Will you be using external drive with other computers, now or in future? If so you want its grub boot on external drive. Default UEFI is to first drive.

No. I will not be using the external drive with other computers. But I would like to know how to make the grub boot on external drive. Also, how to change the boot mode in the BIOS setting?

You should have a setting in UEFI that specifies default boot mode. One of my older systems had that under BIOS settings which seemed upside down as with UEFI BIOS is an option.  New systems now are UEFI only. But many systems let you boot USB live installer in either mode, the setting in UEFI/BIOS settings is default only for installed system. If drive is gpt, you need either bios_grub or ESP for grub to install. Old versions of Ubuntu only installed to "first" drive as defined by UEFI/BIOS even if you choose. With 24.04 or later & newer flavors you get choice, but choosing with ESP to use.
